# How to make a Gui unopenable when a tool isn't equipped in Roblox?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I have a script that opens the scope for a gun on right click in Roblox, but it even opens when right click is not on, I can not figure out how to make it this way.

Script:

````
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local tool ,equipped= script.Parent,false
local uis = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local Ui = script:WaitForChild("ScopeGui")

script.Parent.Unequipped:Connect(function()
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui:FindFirstChild(Ui.Name):Destroy()
end)

tool.Equipped:Connect(function()equipped=true;end)
tool.Unequipped:Connect(function()equipped=false;end)
uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)if not equipped then return end

end)    

    uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, typing)

    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton2 then
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScopeGui.ScopeLbl.Visible = true
        workspace.Camera.FieldOfView = 23.5
        player.CameraMode = Enum.CameraMode.LockFirstPerson
    end
end)

uis.InputEnded:Connect(function(input, typing)

    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton2 then
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScopeGui.ScopeLbl.Visible = false
        wait()
        workspace.Camera.FieldOfView = 70
        wait()
        player.CameraMode = Enum.CameraMode.Classic
        player.CameraMaxZoomDistance=25
        player.CameraMinZoomDistance=7
        end
end)
wait(1)
player.CameraMode = Enum.CameraMode.Classic
player.CameraMinZoomDistance = 0
player.CameraMaxZoomDistance = 25```
````